# Is there a benefit in using the repository pattern to simplify the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created quite a few projects where my business logic has been directly accessing my data layer. Since its the only way I have been setting up my MVC projects, I cannot say for sure where the system has been lacking.

I would, however, like to improve on this. To remove many return functions from my controllers, there are 2 ways I see to achieve the same goal.

1. Including these return functions as methods of the model classes(doesnt make sense, since the datacontext would need to be initialized within every model).
2. Using a repository

After reading up a bit on repositories, I haven't come across any instances where "Thinning your controllers" may be a 'pro' to using a repository(a generic repository, could be related to this).

For an understanding of the answer I am looking for, I would like to know if, besides the above mentioned reason, I should use a repository. Is there really a need for a repository?In this case, my project will only be reading data (Full CRUD functionality wont be needed).

Comment: I read the title alone and I have no idea what you're on about, so it doesn't sum up the question.

Comment: For completeness, @DaveDev commented before the amendment to the title

Comment: What is used for the DAL?  An EF Context can be considered a UoW + Repositories already.

Answer (score 4):

There is definitely a need for a repository. Every class should only have one real responsibility where possible; your controller's job is simply to 'give' information to the view. An additional benefit to this is if that if you do create a repository layer then, providing you make interfaces for them, you can make your solution a lot more testable. If your controller knows how to get data from a database (past using a repository - or similar) then your controller is "doing" more than one thing, which violates the single responsibility principle.

I used to use a generic repository pattern using the library SharpRepository, however I found that I needed more fine-grained control over what each of my repositories had access to (for example, there were some repositories I did not want to have mutation control and only be read-only). As a result I switched back to using non-generic repositories. Any half-decent IOC tool will be able to register your repositories based on convention (i.e, `IFooRepository` maps to `FooRepository`), so the number of classes is not really a factor.

As a commentor mentioned your title doesn't really sum up your question, so I'll summarize it for other answer authors:

> Is there a benefit in using the repository pattern to simplify the controller?

Comment: Thanks, I realised my title didnt even ask a question. I will edit out 1st line